# Runtime error 1004, and sometimes overflow error

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with the following,

I have the following code to look for a number in Column A. Then look if its from 1 to 6, i will have to convert it to test1...test6, if any of 1 to 6 is available.

My code for some reason is showing the runtime error and sometime overflow error. Was wondering if any one can help me with this error. Thank you in advance!

```
Sub macro()

    Dim rownum As Long, colnum As Long, currcell As Range

    rownum = ActiveCell.Row
    colnum = ActiveCell.Column

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    'Converting 1-6 into Test1-Test6
    Do
        Set currcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(rownum, 1)
        If IsNumeric(currcell.Value) Then
            If currcell.Value = 1 Then
                currcell = "test1"
            ElseIf currcell.Value = 2 Then
                currcell = "test2"
            ElseIf currcell.Value = 3 Then
                currcell = "test3"
            ElseIf currcell.Value = 4 Then
                currcell = "test4"
            ElseIf currcell.Value = 5 Then
                currcell = "test5"
            ElseIf currcell.Value = 6 Then
                currcell = "test6"
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        rownum = rownum + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, the overflow error could _maybe_ be there because you're using an infinite loop... Try adding some conditions to stop.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in debug mode? On what line does the error occur?

Comment: It states the error is at 'Set currcell = ActiveSheet.Cells(rownum, 1)
'... Have no idea why it is happening over there... as for the overflow error, it states at 'rownum = rownum + 1'

Comment: Have you considered using `.FIND` and `.FINDNEXT` instead of a loop? From your code it looks like you are searching for a cell which has 6 (`Exit Do`). If you want to replace all instances then you might also want to look at `.REPLACE`

Comment: `rownum As Long, colnum As Long, currcell As Range` You are missing a `Dim` here? Or is it a typo?

Comment: Ok, and what is the value of `rownum` when that happens? I betcha it's 1 greater than the number of rows in a workbook.

Comment: You also might want to upload your workbook for a faster resolution? You can upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here...

Comment: @SiddharthRout, i realized the DIM, it was a typo... I dont think i can use .find because I need to fix the changes to just Column A.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, i believe the rownum is 1 if i do 'rownum = ActiveCell.Row'.. Am I right to assume that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > > > @SiddharthRout, i realized the DIM, it was a typo... I dont think i can use .find because I need to fix the changes to just Column A. – user1204868 1 min ago

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1) '<~~ Col A
        For i = 1 To 6
            .Replace What:=i, Replacement:="test" & i, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False

            DoEvents
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: wow.. thanks! This is alot shorter and faster than what mine can do